# Recipes on OpenGeo Suite

Tags: boundless-suite, geoexplorer

could someone tell me how to add a recipe in OpenGeo Suite please. I would like to submit a [Tree sub-layer](http://suite.opengeo.org/recipes/#basic/sublayer) in a geoexplorer map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official recipe collection for GeoExplorer, but you could contribute your code as plugin to the Suite SDK by submitting a pull request for https://github.com/opengeo/gxp. If you feel that this is more suitable for documentation or a tutorial, then you could contribute to the SDK tutorial by sending a pull request for https://github.com/opengeo/suite/tree/master/docs/usermanual/source/apps/clientsdkintro.